# Why to import jQuery before importing materialize.js Google Material Design

Tags: jquery, materialize

It has been given that JQuery has to be imported before importing materialize.js in Google Material Design. But there is no explaination provided for the same.

Any idea why we need to import jquery before importing materialize.js in Google Material design ??

TIA
Jagan

Comment: Because `materialize.js` internally uses `jquery`

Answer (score 1):

materialize.js is a javascript cdn which uses jquery . So if you will not import jquery cdn then materialize function which use jquery will not run this will give you error. So first you need jquery cdn before materialize.js